# sql postgres Как создать unq index второй аргумент которого надо вычислить.. Или как вычислить default значение запросом

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
  create table moodle.tbl_students_to_groups (
      id serial not null
        constraint tbl_student_to_group_id
            primary key,
        student_id int not null
            constraint to_student
                references moodle.tbl_students(id),
        group_id int not null
          constraint to_group
                references moodle.tbl_groups(id)
    );
```

Нужно создать ограничение на то что студент не может состоять в нескольких группах относящихся к одному курсу

Comment: *Нужно создать ограничение на то что студент не может состоять в нескольких группах относящихся к одному курсу* Обычный составной уникальный индекс по полям (студент, курс). Вот только я что-то не вижу в структуре сведений по тому, к какому курсу какая группа относится.

Comment: Чтобы получить информацию о курсе группы для ограничения из таблицы tbl_groups, требуется запрос, который выберет данные из таблиц tbl_students_to_groups и tbl_groups. Сомневаюсь, что выражение констрейнта допускает запросы к другим таблицам.

Comment: как мне написать что бы 2 часть соcтовного индекса высчитывалось через group_id и таблицу group

Comment: Самым простым выходом вижу добавление в структуру поля курса, написание триггера, который по значению поля группы в записи заполнит значение поля курса (триггеры ничего не имеют против запросов к другим таблицам), и добавление уникального индекса по комбинации (студент, курс).

Comment: С триггером все понятно, но хотелось бы без него. А можно как - ниубдь  сдеалть что бы через select или еще как-то посчитать default value полю course_id, которое я бы добавил в  таблицу?

Comment: Смотрите документацию на предмет запроса в условии констрейнта. Если можно - пишите, если нет - то нет...